# Can't uninstall .NET 5 RC1

Tags: asp.net5

I'm trying to install .NET 4.6.1, but it claims I have a newer version installed and won't let me. I do have .NET 5 installed, so I'm trying to uninstall that. I had two installations, one for RC1 and one for RC1 Update 1. I removed the Update 1 installation, that went fine, but RC1 itself won't uninstall. When I run the uninstaller it opens a prompt to locate `AspNet5.ENU.RC1.exe`. This version of the installer seems to have been wiped from the internet in favor of the RC1 Update 1 installer (`AspNet5.ENU.RC1_Update1.exe`). If I cancel the prompt I get `0x80070642 - User cancelled installation.` If I point it to the Update 1 installer, I get `0x80070001 - Incorrect function.` I'm able to repair with no problems, I just can't uninstall.

How can I fix this so I can properly uninstall .NET 5 RC1?

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://github.com/aspnet/dnvm/issues/254

Comment: @Matthias It doesn't. I don't understand what I have to do. I don't know what that `dnvm` is they are talking about.

Comment: Avoided `asp.net-core` tag, as this is the RC1 only issue.

Comment: November 2020 - Install full version .NET 5 (finally merged net core and net framework) @ https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0

Answer (score 163, accepted):

I had the same issue, I found it by googling the KB id. http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/0/A/B0AEBD7D-6979-4265-B1AC-A0B73618FB22/AspNet5.ENU.RC1_Update1.exe

or this:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/8/0/18048EDD-9F45-479A-B208-6F7C91CF2ECC/AspNet5.ENU.RC1_Update1_KB3137909.exe

Comment: this is the answer but you have to uninstall the files in the order in which they were installed - AspNet5.ENU.RC1_Update1_KB3137909.exe goes first (if you have it)

Comment: In my case, it only worked when I uninstalled **AspNet5.ENU.RC1_Update1.exe** first, followed by uninstalling **AspNet5.ENU.RC1_Update1_KB3137909.exe** second.

Comment: Thank you for providing direct links to the old installers! Great help.

Comment: For me (vs2015/vs2015 update 3 already uninstalled) worked when I run first "AspNet5.ENU.RC1_Update1_KB3137909.exe", and select uninstall. For AspNet5.ENU.RC1_Update1.exe I got error: another version already installed.

Comment: When trying to uninstall using the first executable I always get a "the specified account already exists" error dialog.

Comment: All these links are now broken. Any idea where to get this file now?

Answer (score 8):

I downloaded only AspNet5.ENU.RC1.exe file from here: 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49959
start it and run "uninstall".
The uninstallation procedure with this file, for ASP.NET 5 RC1, works without problems.

Comment: Worth noting that the stated file also gave an error before allowing it to be uninstalled as a previous version still exists. To fix just run it via CMD with the /uninstall flag as follows. `AspNet5.ENU.RC1.exe /uninstall` and then your allowed to hit uninstall

Answer (score 3):

I managed to uninstall it by downloading the installer from [asp.net](https://get.asp.net/) and tried to install it by double clicking on the file. It gave an option to repair and uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reinstalling Windows for an unrelated reason. I made a point of **not installing the update to `Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools`** and the problem has not happened again.

Comment: This isn't specifically targeted at solving the problem at hand.